# oledb excel some date-columns return null

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am reading a xlsx-file via oledb. There are some rows where a column (containing a date-string) returns null and some rows where the column (also containing a date-string) returns the date-string. In excel the column-type is set to "date".

Here is my connection-string:

> $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source={PATH_TO_FILE};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0
>   Xml;HDR=NO\""

Here is the command-text to query the data:

> $"SELECT * FROM [SHEET_NAME$A4:BC] WHERE
>   F1 IS NOT NULL"

Here is how i read the data from the data-record:

```
var test = dataRecord.GetValue(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("F39"));
```

Her are some examples what the inspector shows me when test contains the date-string:

```
{07.01.1975 00:00:00}
{03.08.1987 00:00:00}
{03.10.1988 00:00:00}
{01.05.1969 00:00:00}
{20.12.2016 00:00:00}
{18.07.2011 00:00:00}
```

In other cases the inspector only show:

```
{}
```

Here is a screenshot from the xlsx-document where i have marked a line in red where the return-value is empty and green where the actual date-string is returned:

[image]

The date-strings are formatted like `dd.mm.yyyy`

Why do these rows return an empty value instead of the date-string?

---

As suggested by AndyG i have checked if the date-string values might fail in dependece of the format ("dd.mm.yyyy" vs. "mm.dd.yyyy"). But there are cases which are invalid for "mm.dd.yyyy" that dont fail.

Comment: Are the dates that work in an acceptable mm.dd.yyyy format, whereas those that fail are in dd.mm.yyyy? I.e. US vs UK format.

Comment: "18.07.2011" returns the date-string and would be invalid for "mm.dd.yyyy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to solve the problem, but was able to bypass it, by changing the column-type in Excel to text.

I had to copy the whole xls-file, delete the content of the copy, set the column-type to text, copy the content from the first file and paste it into the second file. Otherwise Excel was changing the date-strings to the numbers which are used to store the date.

Now I can read the cells correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late but after struggling with this for the better part of several hours I hope this might help someone:

It sounds likely the first row in your excel document contains column names and not actual data, which means they are of a different Excel data type (General/Text + DateTime).

The fix to handle is pretty simple - adjust your connection string to reflect this using the HDR property in Extended Properties:

```
$"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={PATH_TO_FILE};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\""
```

HDR = true means the first row contains field names

You can read more about it here:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Additionally, if you are encountering this on odd lines in your document like OP, ensure that the data type is identical for the entire column, except your column titles if using HDR=true
Excel can sometimes flip DateTime fields to General fields which would cause this behavior